# Robotframework JSON value iteration

Tags: arrays, json, automation, robotframework

I'm trying to extract the following data:

```
    ["Gunpla","Wood Craft"]
```

from this JSON

```
    {

    "hobby": {
        "hobbyList": [
            {

                "hobbyType": "Art",

                "hobbyTypeList": [
                    {

                        "hobbyText": "Gunpla",
                         "hobbyIndex": "1",
                          "hobbyOrigin": "JPN"
                        
                    }
                ]
            },
            {

                "hobbyType": "Art",
                "hobbyTypeList": [
                    {

                        "hobbyText": "Wood Craft" ,
                         "hobbyIndex": "2",
                          "hobbyOrigin": "USA"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Using this simple query. I'm having difficulty extracting "HobbyText" from HobbyTypeListArray.

```
    FOR     ${ob_list}      IN      @{json['hobby']['hobbyList']}
            log     ${ob_list["hobbyTypeList"][]}
    END
```

Tried to query it explicitly using this JSONPath

```
$.hobby.hobbyList[.hobbyTypeList[.hobbyText
```

and expected output should be the same as above mentioned. However, after running it on RBF it returns a parse error

```
Parse error at 1:33 near token . (.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare index and call selected obj.

```
    FOR     ${ob_list}      IN      @{json['hobby']['hobbyList']}
        log     ${ob_list["hobbyTypeList"][${index}]['hobbyText]'}
END
```